# React Native - Get an error when using a custom component that I made (Error: undefined Unable to resolve module <MyModule>)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, publish, package.json

I made a custom component called "react-native-weekly-calendar", 
and I'm trying to publish it to open source community, 
but I want to test it first. When I try to test it by `npm install --save ../<component_name>`, it throws an error.

My directory structure:

```
- react-native-weekly-calendar (folder)
    - index.js
    - package.json
    - src (folder)
        - Locale.js
        - Style.js
```

index.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Text, View, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Modal, Platform, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import moment from 'moment/min/moment-with-locales';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import { FontAwesome } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import { applyLocale, displayTitleByLocale } from './src/Locale';
import styles from './src/Style';

const WeeklyCalendar = props => {
    ...
}

export default WeeklyCalendar;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-native-weekly-calendar",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Weekly Calendar component for React Native",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/codeinjuice/react-native-weekly-calendar.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "reactnative",
    "react-native",
    "react-native-component",
    "calendar",
    "weeklycalendar",
    "weekly-calendar",
    "scheduler",
    "datepicker",
    "date-picker"
  ],
  "author": "codeinjuice",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/codeinjuice/react-native-weekly-calendar/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/codeinjuice/react-native-weekly-calendar#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.7",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "~6.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.4"
  }
}
```

Here is how I tested with the files above:

```
$ npx react-native init sample
$ cd sample
$ npm install --save ../react-native-weekly-calendar
$ vim App.js
```

Then I added `import WeeklyCalendar from 'react-native-weekly-calendar';` in App.js.
Finally I ran

```
$ npx react-native run-ios
```

In the simulator, I get this error:

> Unable to resolve module 'react-native-weekly-calendar' from 'App.js':react-native-weekly-calendar could not be found within the project.

Did I set my dependency settings wrong in `package.json`???

I don't understand why it keeps saying the component is not found when it's clearly inside of node_modules folder.

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: Once your dependencies are installed properly, they should appear under attribute `dependencies` or `devDependencies ` in your `package.json` file

Comment: @keikai You mean `package.json` in the tester project? It's `dependencies` contain
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-weekly-calendar": "file:../react-native-weekly-calendar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: I upgraded react-native from 0.60.* to 0.61.4 and it worked with npm as well.**

**Original answer**
I used `$ yarn add ../react-native-weekly-calendar`

instead of `$ npm install --save ../react-native-weekly-calendar` and it worked.